# Get all data by filtering on keyword via xsl:for-each

Tags: xml, xslt

Hello I got a rather simple question I guess. I want to get all the points by checking on a specific keyword.

I have this XML:

```
<Series>
    <Series Name="Dollar">
        <Points>
            <DataPoint XValue="2000" YValues="1.37984" />
            <DataPoint XValue="2001" YValues="1.38572" />
        </Points>
    </Series>
    <Series Name="Pond">
        <Points>
            <DataPoint XValue="2000" YValues="0.7235" />
            <DataPoint XValue="2001" YValues="0.7251" />
        </Points>
    </Series>
</Series>
```

I want to retrieve from all the datapoints the x and y values depending on the series name (Dollar or Pond).

I tried things like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//DataPoint">
    <xsl:value-of select="//Series[@Name='Dollar']/@XValue" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

But nothing what I tried worked. Perhaps someone can guide/help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right expression `//Series[@Name='Dollar']`, only use it in the `for-each`, e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Series[@Name='Dollar']//DataPoint">
    <xsl:value-of select="@XValue" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Ah yes!! Thanks, that make sense! You really helped me!